# Statement performed only when method ends

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I'm C# with Compact Framework and I realized something weird today. I'm calling a method by an event that applies a `set` to an object and when I debug, it passes by this, but just performs after the last close bracket of the method. My example:

```
public string Loading 
{
    set { lblLoading.Text = value; }
}

private void btnAuth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Loading = "Loading...";
    _presenter.PerformAuth();
}
```

When I debug, it passes by my first statement, applies it, but doesn't change anything on the screen... Oh, until it do `PerformAuth()`. After it, so, then the label value is changed. Oh, the problem isn't just by it be synchronous. The same occurs when I try to do an asynchronous task:

```
private void btnAuth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASyncResult res = BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>Loading = "Loading..."));
    EndInvoke(res);
    _presenter.PerformAuth();
}
```

I think it might be a bug in thread and in C# design implementation. And also with direct set it is stubborn to me. As you can see in the image below:

I just want to set a text in a label, call a method and unset it in an event. Why does C# get it so complicated?

[image]

Comment: The UI thread is blocked until `PerformAuth` is completed. Unfortunately I don't have a compact device to test with, but you should be able to do the heavy work `PerformAuth` in a separate thread, to free up the UI thread to update with the changes you make.

Comment: The OS won't update the user interface if you block the UI thread, which you do until you return from event handlers like click events.